# ReactiveUI toggle button binding

Tags: reactiveui

Is it possible to bind a WPF ToggleButton to a pair of ReactiveUI commands?

I'm using the Rx pattern of canceling one observable when the other observable ticks. I would therefore like the toggle ON to trigger the `Connect` command, and the toggle OFF to trigger the `Disconnect` command.

```
Connect = ReactiveCommand
    .CreateFromObservable(() => app.Connection
            .TakeUntil(Disconnect),
        outputScheduler: schedulerProvider.MainThread);

Disconnect = ReactiveCommand.Create(
    () => { },
    Connect.IsExecuting);
```

View.xaml

```
<ToggleButton Name="Toggle" />
```

View.xaml.cs .. not sure how this should work...

```
d(this.BindCommand(ViewModel, x => x.Connect, x => x.Toggle));
d(this.BindCommand(ViewModel, x => x.Disconnect, x => x.Toggle));
```

Any ideas? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I last had to solve this problem, I ended up using `InvokeCommand` like this:

```
d(this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.IsConnected, v => v.Toggle.IsChecked));

d(ViewModel
    .WhenAnyValue(vm => vm.IsConnected)
    .Where(value => value == true)
    .Select(_ => Unit.Default)
    .InvokeCommand(ViewModel.Connect));
d(ViewModel
    .WhenAnyValue(vm => vm.IsConnected)
    .Where(value => value == false)
    .Select(_ => Unit.Default)
    .InvokeCommand(ViewModel.Disconnect));
```

`InvokeCommand` passes the value of the observable into the command, so we need to use a `Select` change the value to a `Unit`.